# Strange filter() behaviour on a table

Tags: jquery

Can someone please look at my demo and tell me why my cell is not getting highlighted?

```
$("#tbl td.rank").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() > 30;
}).addClass('bright');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmftvxyd/6/

I basically want to highlight the cell whose rank > 30

Update: Changed demo link as class had been wrongly mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes:

1)Your selector is wrong. You can add `tr`(optional) and also there is no td with class `.rank`

2)To compare text of each `td` you have first to convert to a number using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
$("#tbl tr td.age").filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 30;
}).addClass('bright');
```

```css
.bright {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="id">EmpNo</th>
      <th class="name">First Name</th>
      <th class="rank">Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">E342</td>
      <td class="name">Bill</td>
      <td class="age">35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">E343</td>
      <td class="name">Laura</td>
      <td class="age">26</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: changed demo link. 'age' was used by mistake.

Comment: Yes but you have to convert `text()` to number to compare. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to convert the checking rank to an Integer so that the value could be compared. ***try to change the color of matching TD text to something else like red to notice the effect.*** try this:

```
$("#tbl td.rank").filter(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) > 30;
}).addClass('bright');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/qmftvxyd/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong class to filter. You should use `td.age`. 
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qmftvxyd/5/)**

```
 $("#tbl td.rank").filter(function () {
     return parseInt($(this).text(),10) > 30;
  }).addClass('bright');
```

Comment: was by mistake. Changed the demo link